# Selenium web driver for button click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the following code snippet to automate the below html code. But, it says 
Unable to locate element:

Solution 1:

```
WebElement element = iedriver.findElement(By.id("rbBC.rbBFC.rbB"));
```

Solution 2:

```
iedriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("btn:contains('Login')")).click()
```

source of HTML

```
<tr id=_vez9u valign=middle>
<td class=ffl></td>
```

Login

*Any help is highly appreciated!*

Thanks!

Comment: tr id=_vez9u valign=middle>
<td class=ffl>
</td><td class=ffi><span id=_hketcc><img alt="" border=0 height=11 width=10 src="cleardot.gif"></span></td>
<td class=ffp>
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=btnWrap><tr><td tabIndex=0 bh=TB id=__vogkb class=btn _cl=btn _isdef=true><div class=rbSA><b class="rbC"><b class="rbBC rb1"></b><b class="rbBC rbFC rb2"></b></b><div class="rbBC rbBFC rbB">
Login </div><b class="rbC"><b class="rbBC rbFC rbBtFC rb2"></b><b class="rbBC rb1"></b></b></div></td></tr></table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the following code

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("__vogkb"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have sued same piece code, it worked! Appreciate your respnse

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
WebElement element = iedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='__vogkb']//div[contains(text(),'Login')]"));
//Or if no other button with login as text
WebElement element = iedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Login')]"));
```

Comment: You were using incorrect locator. You can look at the documentations at: [Selenium Docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp), [Reliable Locator](http://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2013/09/26/writing-reliable-locators-for-selenium-and-webdriver-tests/)

Comment: Tq! Sure!! will check